# A 240 GB SSD for a programmer

Tags: desktop, ssd

I'm looking to upgrade my old HDD to SSD to improve build times while programming. Two primary concerns are random read/write and lingevity of the disk. The budget is under 400 PLN (I'm from Poland, that's around 100 USD)

Due to the price I'm currently looking at Intel's 535 240GB or SanDisk Ultra II Plus 240GB. T so Samsung is pretty much out of my budget from what I gathered, but I will welcome any suggestions.

Edit:
Forgot to include the interface: SATA 3, will most likely go with ASRock's [H170M Pro4](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H170M%20Pro4/)

Edit2:
I forgot to add, this will be used to (among others) build OpenEmbedded which takes ~50GB for a full image build. Not that it really matters, with 75TB meaning 1,5k full rebuilds.

Comment: It would be great if you could specify interface type (SATA, M.2, PCIe, etc). If possible, list the ones you can use, as well as the ones you would prefer to use. Version numbers are good too. Thanks.

Comment: @Alpha3031 interface listed, what do you mean about ones I can usre or would prefer? Two ones I picked before asking the question are already listed in content.

Comment: Well, you'd probably have PCIe, but even if you could afford a NVMe PCIe SSD, you might want to use it for something else. I notice the motherboard has M.2 as well. It does look like the 850 EVO is cheaper on some sites though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving from HDD to any new SSD will be noticable, while the differences between particular SSD tend to be slight. I actually did the same (also ssd upgrade for programming) and just went with the cheapest SSD at the time (Kingston), because my laptop only supported SATA II (300 MB/s). If you have SATA III and want something premium, the Samsung 850 250 GB is your best bet imho, and you can get it for 360 zł in poland: [see allegro](http://allegro.pl/listing/listing.php?order=d&bmatch=base-relevance-ele-1-3-0229&search_scope=&string=Samsung%20850%20evo%20250)

See benchmarks:

- [Samsung 850 Pro VS 840 Evo Benchmark Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?)
- [Samsung 850 pro vs 850 evo benchmark test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6ZZWg4BYRY) (do not go with pro, it's for other use cases and you'd be overpaying)
- Also see SSD buyers [guide from Linus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YsNssB0QPo)

Comment: There have been enough performance-destroying screwups with SSD firmware that I wouldn't want to buy one without seeing both benchmarks and real-world usage tests.

Answer (score 0):

The [Samsung 840 Evo 250GB](http://pcpartpicker.com/part/samsung-internal-hard-drive-mz7te250bw) is priced at around $115 now. Samsung SSDs are known to be very reliable and I think that if the 850 Evo is out of your budget, the 840 Evo would be your best choice.

Comparison between 840 Evo and SanDisk Ultra II Plus [here](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Compare/SanDisk-Ultra-II-240GB-vs-Samsung-840-Evo-250GB/2548vs1594).

Comparison between 840 Evo and Intel 535 [here](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Compare/SanDisk-Ultra-II-240GB-vs-Samsung-840-Evo-250GB/2548vs1594).

Comment: Can you add in some of the results of the benchmarks into your answer?

Comment: Yes, but that's 40% more expensive then intel and 25% over my budget looking at the prices here in Poland :/

Comment: If that is the case, then I would recommend you go with the Crucial MX200. It lasts a long time and delivers great performance. It's selling for roughly $85 so it should be in your budget. It's also great value for money. http://pcpartpicker.com/part/crucial-internal-hard-drive-ct250mx200ssd1

Comment: @JanDorniak In Poland you can get the 850 evo for under 400PLN. Look on ceneo.pl Koputronik for example 399 zł. I got mine for 85€ (~364zł) in Germany on Amazon.

Comment: @szoszk yeah, but I blindly looked for 840 evo which is more expensive :/